# Degrees of freedom for total sum of squares in Linear model without intercept

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models

When we run a linear model with and without intercept, in case of without intercept model we have degrees of freedom for TSS exactly total number of observations in the response variable. Why is it so? we normally have (n-1) df for TSS, where n is the total number of observations in the response variable. But in case of without intercept model , we have exactly n degrees of freedom when we run R code as below:

########### Model 1 -With intercept

```
data(mtcars)
attach(mtcars)
Model1=lm(mpg~hp)
anova(Model1) #### degrees of freedom for regression 1

    Analysis of Variance Table

    Response: mpg
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
    hp         1 678.37  678.37   45.46 1.788e-07 ***
    Residuals 30 447.67   14.92  



################# Model 1 -Without intercept #########

data(mtcars)
attach(mtcars)
Model1=lm(mpg~hp-1) ### model without intercept
anova(Model1) #### degrees of freedom for regression again 1

    Analysis of Variance Table

        Response: mpg
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
        hp         1 8530.8  8530.8  47.982 9.062e-08 ***
        Residuals 31 5511.5   177.8  
My concern is, how come degrees of freedom for TSS remain 32, which should be (32-1) for without intercept model.
```

Comment: You spend one $df$ to estimate the parameter for hp in both cases. In the first case you also spend one on estimating the intercept. You have 30 respectively 31 residual degrees of freedom. What do you mean by df for TSS?

Comment: @Knarpie TSS (Total sum of squares). We have total number of observations 32 in  variable hp. Df( hp+Residuals)=32  in case when we do not use intercept. For TSS df=(32-1) normally, why in case of model without intercept, it is 32

Comment: The total sum of squares is model-independent, and so are its degrees of freedom.